# Given two continuous random variables X and Y with different domains, how can you calculate P(X<Y) given some joint PDF?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given the continuous random variables X and Y.

[image: Domains]

Given some joint PDF [image: PDF]

Determine [image: Question]

I know that usually for these questions you'll integrate the joint PDF with respect to x from 0->y and then integrate with respect to y from 0 -> 400.

[image: Integral]

However, when you do so, doesn't that remove the upper limit from x? The only way that I can come up with to answer this question is to flip it and calculate

[image: Flipped]

in which case I believe the integration would be

[image: Integral].

Is this the only way to solve the problem or am I looking at it the wrong way?
I don't know how I would solve this problem for the domains

[image: Domains]

I feel like there must be some aspect of this that I'm missing. If anyone happens to know the issue in my understanding here I'd love an explanation.

Comment: it would appear that X and Y are not discrete here

Comment: Okay, is it the notation I'm using to show the domain of X and Y? If so, what would be the correct way to show that X and Y are all real numbers within the given range?

Comment: If $X$ is capped at $20$ then you start with
$$
\int_0^{400}\int_0^{\min(y,20)}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_0^{20}\int_0^yf(x,y)\,dx\,dy+\int_{20}^{400}\int_0^{20}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\,.
$$ What tricks we use to calculate this further depends essentially on $f(x,y)\,.$

Comment: Ah I see, thank you!

Comment: @Andrew I mean to say they were continuous, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are finding the bounds for integration for computing $P(X<Y)$, you need to take all inequalities into account. We are given that $0\le x\le 20$ and $0\le y\le 400$. You want to find $P(X< Y)$, which gives another inequality, $x<y$.

If we integrate using $y$ as the outer variable, then our integral is something like this:
$$
\int_0^{400}\int_{?}^{?} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
$$
Let's start with the lower bound on $x$. We look at all of our inequalities, and see that the only one which gives a lower bound on $x$ is $0\le x$. Therefore, the lower bound is just $0$.

For the upper bound, there are two inequalities giving an upper bound on $x$. They are
$$
x<y \qquad \text{and}\qquad x<20
$$
Only the stricter of these two bounds matters, but *which bound is strictest depends on $y$*. When $y< 20$, then the bound on the left is more strict, but when $y>20$, the bound on the right is more strict. This means there is no single upper bound that works for all $y$, so you need to split this into two integrals.
$$
P(X<Y)=\underbrace{\int_0^{20}\int_{0}^{y} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
}_{\text{When $y<20$, strictest bound is $x<y$}}
+
\underbrace{\int_{20}^{400}\int_{0}^{20} f(x,y)\,dx\,dy}_{\text{When $y>20$, strictest bound is $x<20$}}
$$
However, we would have had an easier time if we used $x$ as the outer variable. Then, the result is
$$
P(X<Y)=\int_0^{20}\int_x^{400}f(x,y)\,dy\,dx
$$
To figure out which order is easiest, you can either try both orders, or you can draw the region being integrated over. In this case, the top border of the region is a piece-wise line instead of a simple linear function, which causes the necessity for two integrals.

Comment: I see, that makes sense! Thanks a lot.